# What would be the best way to kill an Dakotaraptor with only stone age weapons?

Tags: combat

Someone in my previous posts pointed out to me that my "end fight" with an [Albertosaurus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albertosaurus) would be unrealistic if I wanted to make it dramatic like with with a man versus a prehistoric beast. So I decided to downgrade it to a [Dakotaraptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakotaraptor)

Going to have my male human protagonist kill an Dakotaraptor with stone age weapons. However as this is in self defense I was just curious to know how one would go about doing it. Like as in a melee battle or through pits.

For context the two characters have been sent back in time to late Cretaceous Midwest America. They're lucky to have found themselves in a situation that they have a semblance of surviving. Nevertheless surviving a year in this hostile environment is going to be difficult.

I want to have my character fight an Dakotaraptor because I believe that that's the largest carnivorous dinosaur and animal they can reasonably kill in the 72-66 MYA era ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maastrichtian). In this case they have to defend someone else  they know on the island. So it's not a planned ambush or something similar to such. Like it's going after them and you have to kill it in a cave or open area or a forest?

Taking down such a large creature with a spear is different do doing it with a bow and arrow. Still in this situation what would be the ideal way to kill a healthy, Adult Dakotaraptor that is, st most, sixty meters away?

Comment: This question may get answers on Worldbuilding, but here on Writing it's 'asking what to write' which is considered off-topic.